# Append Paragraphs to Selection

Tags: vba, ms-word

Office 365; Word v.2205

I am trying to select a series of paragraphs in a Word document. Lets say there are 10 paragraphs in a document, and I only want to select paragraph 3 through 5. Is there a way to to select just those paragraphs by using paragraph objects? I am envisioning something like:

```
ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(3,4,5).Range.Select
```

But, as we know, that does not work.

The larger purpose of my code is to search my document for any "Heading 2" style paragraphs (indicating the beginning of a section). Once it finds "Heading 2", it then needs to select all **subsequent** paragraphs appearing **before** the next "Heading 2" paragraph.

Code posted below:

```
Private Sub selectRange()

Dim oParagraph As Word.Paragraph
Dim oRange, oStartPar As Range
Dim oStyle, oParaStyle, sStartPar, sEndPar As String
Dim iStartPar, iEndPar As Integer
Dim x As Long

' Loop through each paragraph
For Each oParagraph In ActiveDocument.Paragraphs
    ' Set range to the current paragraph
    Set oRange = oParagraph.Range
    ' Get paragraph text
    sPText = oRange.Text
    ' Get style name of paragraph
    oParaStyle = oRange.Style.NameLocal
    ' If style = Heading 2, capture the contents of that section
    If oParaStyle = "Heading 2" Then
        oRange.Select
        Selection.MoveEndUntil (Chr(13))
        Selection.MoveStartUntil (Chr(13))
        Selection.MoveStart Count:=1

        ' Get number of paragraphs in doc
        Set oStartPar = ActiveDocument.Range(Start:=0, End:=Selection.End)
        iStartPar = oStartPar.Paragraphs.Count

        ' Get the number of final paragraph in section of doc
        For x = iStartPar To ActiveDocument.Paragraphs.Count
            sEndPar = ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(x).Style.NameLocal
            If sEndPar = "Heading 2" Then
                iEndPar = x - 1
                Exit For
            End If
        Next      
        ###INSERT CODE TO SELECT PARAGRAPHS ( iStarPar thru iEndPar ) ####
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

In VBA each variable must each be declared with a datatype. In your declarations only 3 variables are correctly typed, the other 5 are all assigned the default datatype of Variant. So, your declarations block should be:

```
Dim oRange As Range As Range, oStartPar As Range
Dim oStyle As String, oParaStyle As String, sStartPar As String, sEndPar As String
Dim iStartPar As Integer, iEndPar As Integer
```

The routine you have created is a very long-winded way of doing something simple. Word's built-in Find function can be used to find formatting such as styles and will be considerably faster than crawling through the paragraphs. Word also has a number of [predefined bookmarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/word/Concepts/Miscellaneous/predefined-bookmarks), one of which will return the range of a heading level, i.e. all paragraphs between two headings with the same outline level.

The function below uses this method to return a heading block as a range:

```
Public Function GetHeadingBlock(headingText As String, headingStyle As WdBuiltinStyle) As Range
   Dim findRange As Range
   Set findRange = ActiveDocument.Content
   With findRange.Find
      .ClearFormatting
      .Replacement.ClearFormatting
      .Text = headingText
      .Style = headingStyle
      .Replacement.Text = ""
      .Forward = True
      .Format = True
      .Wrap = wdFindStop
      If .Execute Then Set GetHeadingBlock = _
         findRange.GoTo(What:=wdGoToBookmark, name:="\HeadingLevel")
   End With
End Function
```

Usage:

```
Sub TestGetHeadingBlock()
    Dim targetRange As Range
    Set targetRange = GetHeadingBlock(headingText:="", headingStyle:=wdStyleHeading2)
    targetRange.Select
End Sub
```

Once you have range of the heading block you can then perform whatever further processing you need to, but I would advise against using `Selection`.

Comment: Can I use find to return multiple heading blocks? For instance, if I have a document with 40 heading blocks, and 15 of them contain a key phrase, can I use find to select each of those 15 heading blocks?

Comment: Also, thank you for enlightening me about the variable declaration issue. I copied someone else's way of doing things and had no idea it was declaring the variable incorrectly.

Comment: @LoganPrice - you cannot select non-contiguous ranges. You would need to create a routine that executes Find in a loop and processes each match individually.